# How to rotate 1D piecewise function around Y axis in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, rotation

I have a 1D piecewise shape which looks like a rectangular with smooth edges (quarter circles):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

def piecewise(x, r, d, h):
    if  -d/2 <= x <= - d/2 + r or d/2- r <= x <= d/2:
        return np.sqrt(r**2-(x-np.sign(x)*d/2+np.sign(x)*r)**2)+r+(h-2*r)
    elif -d/2 - r <= x <= -d/2 or d/2 <= x <=  d/2 + r:
        return -np.sqrt(r**2-(x- np.sign(x)*d/2-np.sign(x)*r)**2)+r
    elif - d / 2 + r < x < d / 2 - r:
        return 2*r+(h-2*r)
    return 0.0

vpiecewise = np.vectorize(piecewise)

x = np.linspace(-20, 20, 10000)
z = vpiecewise(x, 4, 20, 10)

plt.plot(x, z, '-')
plt.show()
```

I would like to rotate it around Y-axis which is its centre to get a cyllinder with smoothed out edges. Is there a way to do it in Python?

Comment: What is a "2D cylinder"?  If you rotate any shape in 2D it would become a circle.

Comment: Sorry, I meant rotating a 1D function of a rectangle to get a cyllinder.

Comment: Search for ["solid of revolution"](https://www.google.de/search?q=matplotlib+solid+of+revolution+site:stackoverflow.com)